# Python3.8: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers

Tags: python, python-3.8

With Python 3.8, is there a reason why `00` or `000000` are valid while `03` yields an error?

```
>>> 000
0

03
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    03
     ^
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers
```

Comment: Yeah that was the question. 00000 works while 03 won't work.

Comment: ah sorry, I misread that! nevermind...

Comment: No problem.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Python's constants derived from C, where integers starting with a 0 are interpreted in octal.  So, `0377` has the decimal value 255.  Over time, Python was changed to the `0o` prefix, but C still allows the `0` prefix.  To avoid any potential confusion, the `0` prefix is now a syntax error.

Comment: I think the key issue, though, is why is `00` or `00000` allowed, i.e., leading zeros are not allowed *unless it's all zeros*. See the linked duplicate, it links to various bug reports, it seems, this really was something that slipped passed in the implementation that goes against the PEP that describes the behavior, but it won't be fixed. EDIT: For the record, I didn't downvote,

Comment: reading the duplicate question, the reason seems to be that 0 is less ambiguous than the other numbers as it has the same value in all the bases. some remarked that all the one digit numbers have the same property, but if we consider that no integer should start with 0 then 0 is already an exception.